# How display dummy image if return type of api is "no Image" using angualrJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have a api which return image if the image is on server corresponding to that id, if image is not there than, it return json response **"No Image"**.

So, when "No Image" response is come at that time I have to use dummuy image using angularjs.

Here is my code:

```
server = "http://localhost:8000/"
            $scope.image = function (id) {
                return test = server + 'api/image/' + id;
            };
```

HTML code:

```
     <img width = 100px; height:60px; ng-src="{{image(n.userID)}}"  alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Please tell me how can I put dummy image if "No Image" is there?....

Comment: Ever heard of the if...else syntax ? -_-

Comment: Yes heard and also try but not working....because if image is in data base it directly display the image, and if image is not there  then it return json response....

Comment: More code please, because apart from a simple `if (id == "No image")` I don't get what the problem is.

Comment: I am using that much code that I have post.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/havuy/2/edit you can use ng-show/hide to display proper image or 'no image' placeholder

```
 <img width = 100px; height:60px; ng-src="{{image(n.userID)}}"  alt="" class="img-responsive" ng-show="image(n.userID)!='no image'" />
  <img ng-src="http://www.isrj.net/ArticleImage/No_Image.jpg" ng-hide="image(n.userID)!='no image'">
```

Comment: This is also not working, when there is no image at that time I am getting this json response "{"error":true,"details":"No image."}", otherwise api return image itself....

Comment: what I am asking is when image is in database then it return image not json response so how can I use if statement....I am confused....and if I am trying with $http.get that time I am not getting any response that time my page display nothing....everything go form page..

Comment: @PreetySapra can you please create jsbin with your code, is difficult to advise if I can see only bit of your solution

Answer (score 1):

I created a very simple Angular directive that would hide the img element whenever there was an error.

```
angular.module('SomeModuleName', [])
.directive('hideEmptyImage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.error(function(err) {
                elem.hide();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Like I said, very simple.
Then for every image I wanted to hide I would simply:

```
<img hide-empty-image ng-src="{{n.userID}}" />
```

In your case where you're wanting to replace the image with a default value I would use this same concept. I would first change the name of the directive, because it's logical, right?. Then set the ng-src attribute on error:

```
.directive('defaultImage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.error(function(err){
                attrs.$set('ngSrc', '/path/to/default.png');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Your html would look like this:

```
<img default-image width = 100px; height:60px; ng-src="{{image(n.userID)}}"  alt="" class="img-responsive"/>
```

With this directive if there is no image then it will replace it with the default image. Simple.